# xamarin form listview image binding

Tags: image, listview, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.listview

If I add an item to a listview, the items is added but the image is not showed. I have to restart application to view it.

The Item is correctly added but the image is not visible.

here the cs.

```
ObservableCollection<Libreria> items = new ObservableCollection<Libreria>(new Libreria().GetLibrerie());

            public Home()
            {
                InitializeComponent ();



                lstLibrerie.ItemsSource = items;
                //pickerLibrerie.ItemsSource = new Libreria().GetLibrerie();


            }

            public void Reload(Libreria newLib)
            {

                items.Insert(0, newLib);

            }
```

here the xaml

```
 <ListView x:Name="lstLibrerie" RowHeight="120">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <ScrollView> <!-- left, top, right, bottom -->
                                <StackLayout Margin="0,20,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="8*" />
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <Image Margin="20,0,0,0" Source="{Binding Icona}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" Aspect="AspectFit" HeightRequest="120"></Image>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding Label}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" FontAttributes="Bold"   />
                                        <Label Text="{Binding DataUltimaApertura}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"   />
                                        <Label Text="{Binding EtichettaNrOggetti}"  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"  />
                                        <BoxView HeightRequest="1" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" Color="Black" />
                                    </Grid>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </ScrollView>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

Can help me? Thanks in advance

Comment: Try setting HasUnevenRows to true on the listview, and unsetting rowheight. I've found with ListView that it will not resize or redraw when there are changes that would cause the list or cells to change unless those properties are set.

Comment: thanks max hamptom but the problem still remain.

Comment: What is the type of property Icona on Libreria?

Comment: the field Icona is a string

Comment: You have a scrollview in a viewcell? That’s an interesting approach. Have you tried removing that and just have he stack layout?

Comment: Remove scroll view from the view cell

Comment: Is `Icona` a image url string or a local image's name?

Comment: @skin and g. mich i removed the scrollview from the viewcell and now thre is only the stack layout but the problem still remain.

Comment: @jack hua: Icona is a string with local name.

Comment: @luna80 what if you remove the binding to the image and hardcode the image name in XAML?

Comment: @luna80 Have you tried my solution below? Any problem?

Comment: to all who are helping me, If I scroll the listview after the item is added (a little bit, just to hide) the image will appear..

Answer (score 0):

I use your code to write a simple demo to update the images in the listView, add a item every 2 second:

**Code in MainPage**:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    ObservableCollection<Libreria> items = new ObservableCollection<Libreria>();

    int a = 0;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        items.Add(new Libreria("1", "Images"));

        lstLibrerie.ItemsSource = items;
        //pickerLibrerie.ItemsSource = new Libreria().GetLibrerie();          

        Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), () =>
        {
            if (a == 0)
            {
                Reload(new Libreria("2", "Images"));
                a = 1;
            }else if (a == 1)
            {
                Reload(new Libreria("3", "Images1"));
                a = 2;
            }
            else if(a == 2)
            {
                Reload(new Libreria("4", "Images2"));
                a = 0;
            }

            return true;
        });
    }

    public void Reload(Libreria newLib)
    {

        items.Insert(0, newLib);

    }
}

public class Libreria  : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    string myLabel;

    public string Label
    {
        set
        {
            if (myLabel != value)
            {
                myLabel = value;

                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Label"));
                }
            }
        }
        get
        {
            return myLabel;
        }
    }

    string icon;

    public string Icona
    {
        set
        {
            if (icon != value)
            {
                icon = value;

                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Icona"));
                }
            }
        }
        get
        {
            return icon;
        }
    }

    public Libreria(string label, string cona) {

        Label = label;
        Icona = cona;        
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

I removed the **ScrollView** from the ViewCell and the other **xaml** code is same as you.

Let have a look at the result:

[image: update Image]

Reply me if you have any questions.

Comment: thanks a lot @jack hua, your example works but not my listview, I can't understand what I'm missing

Comment: @luna80 OK, Is your model inherits from `INotifyPropertyChanged`? Did the label update when you add item? Also, you can add you code of `Libreria` to your question and I will check it for you.

Comment: is the model inherits from INotifyPropertyChanged. The label is correctly added but not the image. now I will attach a screenshot to explain me better and the Libreria code

Comment: Well, I can't reproduce your problem so far. Can you try different images in your drawable?

Comment: Yes, I tried differents image but with the same behaviour

Comment: @luna80 What version of Xamarin.forms are you using? I'm using 3.4.0.1008975. You can try a different version.

Comment: I'm using the 3.6.0.264807. I can try another one. The strange is also that if  I launch UWP all works

Comment: I tried your version @jack hua, but the problem still remain. in ios I can't try for the moment

Comment: @luna80 Have you solved it? I'm curious about the cause.

Comment: thanks @jack hua, no, I still have the problem and I don't know what to do...it seems so easy to solve but not. You are so kindly that I ask you if maybe have to use the INotifyCollectionChanged oterwise the INotifyPropertyChanged. What do you think?

Comment: @luna80 No need to change INotifyPropertyChanged. Can you create a new project with the simplest code to reproduce the problem and then upload to Github. Then I can download and check it.

Comment: hua off course, I can do that! I appreciate your help, Thanks! I'll write here the link after I uploaded the sample project on githubt.

Comment: @luna80 Sure, I will check it once you write the link.

Comment: hua I have a good news, I solved! The problem was an async method. The copy of the image wasn't completed. Calling the copy method with await did the trick. In any way thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @luna80 Glad to hear that:).

Answer (score 0):

[here the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1eZw.png)

```
public class Libreria : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Tipo Tipo { get; set; }
    public int IdTipo { get; set; }
    public int NrOggetti { get; set; }

    public string DataUltimaApertura { get; set; }
    string _label;
    string _icon;


    public Libreria()
    {
    }

    public string Label
    {
        set
        {
            if (_label != value)
            {
                _label = value;

                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Label"));
                }
            }
        }
        get
        {
            return _label;
        }
    }


    public string Icona
    {
        set
        {
            if (_icon != value)
            {
                _icon = value;

                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Icona"));
                }
            }
        }
        get
        {
            return _icon;
        }
    }

    public string EtichettaNrOggetti
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Format("Nr. elementi: {0}", NrOggetti);
        }
    }


public List<Libreria> GetLibrerie()
    {
        string query = string.Format("SELECT COUNT(oggetto.idlibreria) AS NrOggetti, Label, IdTipo, DataUltimaApertura, Icona FROM libreria LEFT JOIN oggetto ON libreria.id = oggetto.idlibreria GROUP BY libreria.id ORDER BY dataultimaapertura DESC");

        return App.DBConnection.Query<Libreria>(query);
        // return App.DBConnection.Table<Libreria>().OrderByDescending(lib => lib.Dataultimaapertura).ToList();
    }

    public Guid Insert()
    {
        this.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        string query = string.Format("INSERT INTO libreria(id, idtipo, label, dataultimaapertura, icona) VALUES('" + this.Id + "'," + this.IdTipo + ",'" + this.Label + "', '" + this.DataUltimaApertura + "', '" + this.Icona + "')");

        App.DBConnection.Execute(query);

        return this.Id;

    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```