# Binding image in listview

Tags: c#, image, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am relatively new to xamarin, and I am currently trying to bind images to my listview, but no matter what I try, I can't seem to get them to display.

Here is my code:

Xaml:

```
 <ListView x:Name="memDisplayGrid" BackgroundColor="Transparent" HeightRequest="575" WidthRequest="200" ItemsSource="{Binding Members}"
                     RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=X, Factor=1, Constant=40}"
                     RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Y, Factor=1, Constant=330}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <Grid Padding="10">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Image x:Name="memAVI" Grid.Column="0" Source="{x:Binding AviSource}" Aspect="AspectFill"/>
                                <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{x:Binding name}" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                            </Grid>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

Code behind:

```
        private void InitializeMembersBlank()
        {
            Members = new List<Member>();
            
            for (int i = 0; i < App.UserDB.GetSpecificUser((int)App.Current.Properties["currentUser"]).MemeberNum; i++)
            {
                Members.Add(new Member
                {
                    AviSource = new Image { Source = "defaultAVI_48x48.jpg" },
                    systemID = i,
                    name = "Member " + (i + 1)
                }) ;
            }
        }
```

Member.cs:

```
public class Member
    {
            public string name { get; set; }
            public string pro_noun { get; set; }
            public string birthday { get; set; }
            public string role { get; set; }
            public int systemID { get; set; } // how is this being set???
            public string description { get; set; }
            public Image AviSource { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "" + name + " /" + pro_noun + " /" + role + " /" + systemID; 
        }
    }
```

Please note that I have tried changing AviSource to ImageSource and a String, but neither was working for me. I can get other things to display but not the image.

[image]

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: 1) `AviSource` should be a string, 2) `Source="{Binding AviSource}"`, 3) be sure you are binding to **public properties**, 4) where is "defaultAVI_48x48.jpg" stored in your project?

Comment: Okay, thanks for the tips! "defaultAVI_48x48.jpg" is stored in my images folder and used as an embedded resource

Comment: be sure you are storing images as specified in the docs - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows

Comment: What do you mean by binding to public properties?

Comment: binding only works with public properties.  They need to have a `get' and be marked as `public`

Comment: Perhaps its that im not updating the view after I add the image?

Comment: if that were the problem it would effect all of your data, not just the images.  Did you read the docs on images and verify that you were storing them correctly?

Comment: Yes and I believe I am. Typically I have the images stored in my Images folder in the shared, non-platform-specific project. According to that link, the image's build action should be either embedded resource or content. I have tried both with neither working.

Comment: I suggest you read them again - "Because there is no built-in type converter from string to ResourceImageSource, these types of images cannot be natively loaded by XAML." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows#xaml

Comment: Ahh... I glossed over that little caveat... Thanks! I got it somewhat working now!

Answer (score 1):

try like this example

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Monkeys}"
      HasUnevenRows="true"
      ItemSelected="OnListViewItemSelected"
      ItemTapped="OnListViewItemTapped">
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
            <Grid Padding="10">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Image Grid.RowSpan="2"
                       Source="{Binding ImageUrl}"
                       Aspect="AspectFill"
                       HeightRequest="60"
                       WidthRequest="60" />
                <Label Grid.Column="1"
                       Text="{Binding Name}"
                       FontAttributes="Bold" />
                <Label Grid.Row="1"
                       Grid.Column="1"
                       Text="{Binding Location}"
                       VerticalOptions="End" />
            </Grid>
        </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

[image]

---

or you can use xamarin.forms listview image cells

```
TableView tableView = new TableView
        {
            Intent = TableIntent.Form,
            Root = new TableRoot
            {
                new TableSection
                {
                    new ImageCell
                    {
                        // Some differences with loading images in initial release.
                        ImageSource =
                            Device.OnPlatform(ImageSource.FromUri(new Uri("http://xamarin.com/images/index/ide-xamarin-studio.png")),
                                              ImageSource.FromFile("ide_xamarin_studio.png"),
                                              ImageSource.FromFile("Images/ide-xamarin-studio.png")),
                        Text = "This is an ImageCell",
                        Detail = "This is some detail text",
                    }
                }
            }
        };
```

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/customizing-cell-appearance#imagecell[enter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/customizing-cell-appearance#imagecell%5Benter) link description here][1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/customizing-cell-appearance#imagecell)

---

- and I found same question in here
  [xamarin form listview image binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55361341/xamarin-form-listview-image-binding)